# django 1.3 admin site problem itself

Tags: python, django, admin

I have got a really strange issue with the admin site. When I enter to the site the address is:http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ and I see the front-admin-site, hmm looks fine. But when I click to any "+Add button" or any link on the site I see still the admin site:p but with address f.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/category/category/add/ . I can play as many times as I want, I see all the time the front-admin-site with a list of my models but with address f.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/category/category/add/category/category/add/category/category/add/category/category/add/ :pp

What is wrong?
Best regards,

nykon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a problem with your urls.py configuration, the way to have admin in there is:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

...

```
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

99% of the time that's what that is.

Comment: I had got (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.urls), I have changed it, and now it works, my mistake, Thank YOU:d